# Universal Image Loader - How Do I Load a Second Image Into an ImageView?

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I am trying to use UIL to load a low-res image, then subsequently load in a high-res version when it is ready.  The problem I am having is that only the first call to imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap); is being executed.  The high-res image never is put into the image view.

I am using version 1.8.6, and it seems that the subsequent request is being cancelled by the call to engine.cancelDisplayTaskFor(imageView); in DisplayBitmapTask.  What is wrong with my code?  How do I avoid cancelling the subsequent displayImage() request?

```
public static DisplayImageOptions.Builder getDefaultDisplayImageOptions() {
    return new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565) // Will be overridden by decodingOptions()
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisc(true)
            .displayer(new SimpleBitmapDisplayer()); // default
}

public static void displayImageWithPlaceholder(final ImageView imageView, final String imageUrl, final String previewImageUrl) {
    DisplayImageOptions.Builder builder = getDefaultDisplayImageOptions();
    DisplayImageOptions displayImageOptions = builder.displayer(new SimpleBitmapDisplayer2()).build();

    ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(
            previewImageUrl,
            imageView,
            displayImageOptions,
            new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {

                @Override
                public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                    // Turn off cache in memory for this call getting the larger images.
                    // It will still be cached on disk if possible.
                    DisplayImageOptions.Builder builder = getDefaultDisplayImageOptions();
                    DisplayImageOptions displayImageOptions = builder.cacheInMemory(false).displayer(new SimpleBitmapDisplayer2()).build();
                    ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imageUrl, imageView, displayImageOptions, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {});
                }
            }
    );
}

private static class SimpleBitmapDisplayer2 implements BitmapDisplayer {
    @Override
    public Bitmap display(Bitmap bitmap, ImageView imageView, LoadedFrom loadedFrom) {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

Comment: `SimpleBitmapDisplayer` and `SimpleBitmapDisplayer2` are exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

At this time the logic of UIL is following: at first callback `onLoadingComplete(...)` is executed and then task for current `Imageview` marked as cancelled. So your second task for full-sized image is canceled.

You can solve this problem only by changing the UIL's sources. Copy them into your project or add UIL: project as Android library dependency.
And then swap two lines 74 and 75 in `DisplayBitmapTask` class. I.e.
replace

```
listener.onLoadingComplete(imageUri, imageView, displayedBitmap);
engine.cancelDisplayTaskFor(imageView);
```

with

```
engine.cancelDisplayTaskFor(imageView);
listener.onLoadingComplete(imageUri, imageView, displayedBitmap);
```

Comment: Any plans to include this in the official source code?

Comment: I think it can be in next release. Let me think about it.